# Wordpress WP-API get images attached to post

Tags: php, json, wordpress

so I am trying to use WP-API plugin:

i figured out how to get all posts for custom post type:

```
http://domain/wp-json/posts?type[]=customType
```

and i figured out how to get attachments:

```
http://domain/wp-json/media/
```

Now the problem is how to get images attached to single post. if I look at the [soruce](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/master/lib/class-wp-json-media.php) it seems to suggest a path like:

```
http://domain/wp-json/media/<postId>/
```

but  I get an error:

```
[{"code":"json_post_invalid_type","message":"Invalid post type"}]
```

any Idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this moment this functionality does not seem to be supported probably will be when the plugin goes into core but for now it is as is.

I ended up making my own json API to serve my needs by making the page templates recive emit JSON data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "parent" id argument, e.g:

```
$ curl http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=<id>
```

where  is the post's ID. What we do is ignore all versions of images except the original, which is found by looking for the GUID > rendered value, e.g:

```
guid: {
    rendered: "http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-content/uploads/image-belonging-to-this-post.png"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just an update to this old post. WP-API now supports getting media related to a particular post.

http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/media/

**Code:**

```
$ curl http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/media/<id>
```

Comment: This will only get you all versions of an original image's ID.

Comment: This will only give you medias by ID and not the medias related to a post